# Javascript: removing an event listener attached with an anonymous function to an object's method

Tags: javascript, event-handling

e.g.:

```
function myclass (htmlelement) {
  this.element = htmlelement;
}

myclass.prototype.hoverfunc = function() {
  alert (this.element.id);
}

myclass.prototype.doListen = function() {
  this.element.addEventListener ('mouseover', function() {this.hoverfunc();}.bind(this),false);
}

elListen = new myclass (document.getElementById('foo'));
elListen.doListen();
```

How would I create a method that would remove the listener from the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to keep the anonymous function?

```
myclass.prototype.doListen = function() {
  this.listener = function() {this.hoverfunc();}.bind(this);
  this.element.addEventListener ('mouseover', this.listener, false);
}


myclass.prototype.stopListen = function() {
  this.element.removeEventListener('mouseover', this.listener);
}
```

Also, be careful with `addEventListener()/removeEventListener()` since they are DOM Level 2 standards based - something IE doesn't do.

Comment: When I try it like you did - it seems that the called hoverfunc doesn't recognize the right 'this' that I need (the object's scope) - this.element is undefined; While, when I try it as I firstly described (using the anonymous function) - it works as it should and the hoverfunc has the right 'this' scope. I'm not completely sure why... but anyway this still leaves me with the problem that if I do it that way, I don't have a way to remove the listener...

Comment: Could you try doing `this.listener = function() { alert(this); this.hoverfunc();}.bind(this);` just to verify what `this` is when you get inside the event handler. What framework are you using to get the .bind() extension of function?

Comment: It looks like it's working now; using the method you described. it probably didn't work the first time because I've had some leftovers from a different test or something :). anyway, thanks for the help and the quick replies Martin.